# Optimize ST_Distance_Sphere query

Tags: mysql

### Geographical Distance Calculation Optimization

I am currently working on a geographical data processing task involving the calculation of distances between a specified geographical point and entries in an address table. The objective is to compile a list of addresses where the calculated distance falls within a predefined range.

The address table under consideration contains the following fields:

| Street | City | Zip Code | Country | Lat | Lon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| StreetName1 | CityName1 | 12345 | Country1 | 12.345678 | -45.67890 |
| StreetName2 | CityName2 | 23456 | Country2 | 23.456789 | -56.78901 |
| StreetName3 | CityName3 | 34567 | Country3 | 34.567890 | -67.89012 |

To perform distance calculations, I have implemented the `ST_Distance_Sphere` function. In addition, I have created a database view based on this address table and executed queries against the view. Here is an illustrative example of the query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM address_view
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(point(Lat, Lon), point(:given_lat, :given_lon)) < :specified_range;
```

However, I am facing concerns regarding the performance of this process. Calculating the distance for all records in the address table is resource-intensive. Therefore, I am seeking recommendations and strategies to optimize the efficiency of this operation. Specifically, I am interested in query optimization techniques or indexing solutions that would enhance the performance while ensuring the accurate retrieval of addresses falling within the specified distance range.

I seek guidance on efficiently using the `ST_Distance_Sphere` function to calculate distances between a geographical point and addresses within a view. My goal is to retrieve addresses that meet specific distance criteria while maintaining performance standards.

Any insights on query optimization or indexing strategies are appreciated.

Comment: make spatial index and mskr s polygon aroud your given point with a radius of specified_range and then check if it is in(contain) that polygon, that wpuld use the spatial index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Fetching* all the rows of the table is the performance burden.

There are several ways to take advantage of "within the specified distance range".  By using a "bounding box", there are multiple solutions using INDEX, SPATIAL, or even PARTITION.  See [*Find Nearest*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql)

If you continue with `POINT` a slight improvement is to precompute the "point" for each row from the lat/lng and keep such in a separate column.